# by default are component thru hole pads in Via style in Eagle software?

Tags: eaglecad

If I go in to Display / Layers, I can see the bottom and top routes, and if I click on Pads, I can see the pads, and because I have Top and Bottom routes, and not using surface mount components, I assume the Pads are on both sides, however I can't find any indication that the hole pads are Via style - Is this just a standard for the machine shops?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What I _think_ you mean is _Plated-Through Holes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.

This is the default for everything, and you have to jump through hoops to have your manufacturer *not* plate the holes, at least for the cheap ones that I use.

Normally, if there is any copper over the drill hit, they will plate the hole, but you have to check with the individual manufacturer. Seeedstudio, which I sometimes use, has a more [confusing solution](http://support.seeedstudio.com/knowledgebase/articles/942234-how-can-i-do-if-i-do-not-required-to-make-plated-t), where you have to encoded it in the solder mask layer.

Comment: Good stuff, nice to know, about to do my first order :-)